# Is it possible to implement vertical tabs in Kendo UI using AngularJS?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, angularjs, kendo-ui

Is it possible to implement vertical tabs in Kendo UI?

I want the result to be similar to this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try vertical tab in UI bootstrap

```
<tabset vertical="true" type="navType">
    <tab heading="Vertical 1">Vertical content 1</tab>
    <tab heading="Vertical 2">Vertical content 2</tab>
</tabset>
```

Go through this page for reference
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: this is for angular, is there anything for kendo ui? I tried the anwer of nklein below, but the elements inside the tabs did not behaved well, I mean they are scattered inside the tab.

Answer (score 2):

No, Kendo UI doesn't include a vertical tabstrip widget for the time being.

**!!UPDATE!!**

Kendo UI now supports tab orientation - vertical and bottom tabs. Here is an a [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/tab-position).

Comment: How can we achieve it?

Comment: You can't achieve it with Kendo UI. This is what I said in my response.

Comment: Please provide any other  alternative to use vertical tab .

Comment: As I said two times Kendo UI does not include a vertical tabstrip widget. Try searching online for another vertical tabstrip component.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment

Answer (score 1):

Just add

class  "tabstrip-vertical"

**CSS**

```
.k-widget.k-tabstrip.tabstrip-vertical {
    /*Width of the tabs*/
    padding-left:12em;
    border-style:none;

}

    .k-widget.k-tabstrip.tabstrip-vertical > ul.k-tabstrip-items {
        left:0px;
        position:absolute;
        border-style:none;

    }

        .k-widget.k-tabstrip.tabstrip-vertical > ul.k-tabstrip-items > li.k-item {
            display:block;
            border-radius:4px 0 0 4px;
            border-width:1px 0 1px 1px;
            /*Width of the tabs*/
            width:12em;
            border-style:none;

        }

            .k-widget.k-tabstrip.tabstrip-vertical > ul.k-tabstrip-items > li.k-item.k-state-active {
                border-right-color:#fff;
                border-right-width:1px;
                border-style:none;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Vertically-oriented Tabstrips have been added to the Q1 2015 Kendo UI release.

You can find more details here: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tabstrip/tab-position

Comment: I did not find any example which tells how to consume tabPosition attribute (https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/tabstrip/configuration/tabposition) in angularJS application. Will be glad if I get one from here.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQueryUI

It has vertical tab component.

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

This link has the demo as well.

Answer (score 0):

As nklein mentioned it's a new feature.
Any way if you can't get the new version you can always use the menu bar, it has orientation support.